# Stripe 3dSecure createSource set custom parameter in redirect url

Tags: javascript, php, stripe-payments

I'm unable to set a custom parameter in 3dSecure create source function, is someone know? I have tried some methods but it overrides my URL parameters.

When I added redirect url something:  `return_url: "www.example.com?orderid=10",` after 3dSecure authorization it redirect me at `www.example.com?client_secret=xyz&livemode=false&source=sdf`

I can't get my `orderid` variable when it returns back on my site as I need to update the order.

Seriously very poor implementation of 3dSecure by Stripe. They mentioned in their docs that you can set custom GET params but not given an example.
[You may include any other GET parameters you may need when specifying redirect](https://stripe.com/docs/sources/three-d-secure#customer-action)

```
   stripe.createSource({
         type: 'three_d_secure',
         amount: totalAmount,
         currency: "eur",
         three_d_secure: {
             card: result.source.id
         },
         redirect: {

             return_url: "www.example.com?orderid=10",
         }
     }).then(function(result2) {

      });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I whipped up a working example from something I had written up previously.  You can find it here:

https://jsfiddle.net/78y1brho/

Basically, it uses Stripe.js/v2 to make a token from the input box, then a card source from the resulting token.  You can ignore that though.  The part that matters is the code in the `populateCard()`-function on Line #33.

That code is where you setup the return variable.  When I did this, it worked fine and returned me to:

`https://test.test.test/myresponse?client_secret=src_client_secret_xxx&livemode=false&source=src_xxx&this=atest`

The notable part being the `this=atest` at the end.  I think maybe it's just that you're missing a protocol (https://) in your url that it's trimming everything.  Maybe try including that?

Comment: you great, Thank you so much, really appreciated. I was missing https protocol and was testing at localhsot.